# How can I link the SFML library to cmake?

Tags: cmake, sfml

I'm trying to make a c++ project using the sfml library on Ubuntu (using vscode, if that matters).

In the past, I used to compile sfml using this:
 `g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

But as of lately i started using Cmake for C++ projects, and now I find myself struggling to include sfml correctly.

Edit: Here's my cmakelists file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(test VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -std=c++17 -Werror -Wextra -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```